# JS: Printing the entire global window object to inspect its contents with search

Tags: javascript, dom, window

Is it possible to convert the entire global Window object to sting and print it out in a browser console (or anywhere else). The goal is to have its contents searchable (so any suggestions that come to mind, any hacks or tricks are welcome).

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: To search for values of properties and properties themselves. Basically to be more flexible as a QA, not being able to check the names of the variables and objects from the source code. I think that would be beneficial for me.